# android :: using Android's Brightness control interface from activity

Tags: android, brightness

In my application i need to change the screen brightness. I want to display Android's internal brightness control dialog box (which is being displayed when we select Settings->Sound and display -> brightness) to be displayed when user clicks brightness button in my activity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this.  The best you can do is launch the Sound and display panel with the intent action defined in android.provider.Settings

Comment: I have done this by adding custom alert dialog box with SeekBar in it. and other code to get and set per activity brightness. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

am start -a android.intent.action.SHOW_BRIGHTNESS_DIALOG